# Need to remove contents of SCHEMA class before logging in with Parse Server

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-server

I am having an issue with a self-hosted Parse Server, everytime I go to log in, I am required to remove the contents of the SCHEMA class.

Here is what I am doing with the login

```
PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "user_birthday", "email"], block: {
user, error in

JTProgressHUD.showWithStyle(JTProgressHUDStyle.Gradient)

    if user == nil {
        print("Error Logging In")
        JTProgressHUD.hideWithTransition(.Default)
    }
    if user != nil {
        print("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
        JTProgressHUD.showWithStyle(JTProgressHUDStyle.Gradient)

        let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/?fields=picture.height(512).width(512),first_name,birthday,gender,bio,email", parameters: nil)
        graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({
            connection, result, error in
            print("ERROR: \(error)")


            guard let r = result as? NSDictionary else {
                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                }
                return
            }

            print(connection)
            print(result)


            if let e = error { print(e) }
            user!["firstName"] = r["first_name"]
            user!["gender"] = r["gender"]
            user!["pictureString"] = ((r["picture"] as! NSDictionary)["data"] as! NSDictionary) ["url"]
            //BIO
            user!["bio"] = "Thanks for Downloading Root or Boot, Please Enter a Bio by Clicking Here"

            if (r["bio"] != nil){
                user!["bio"] = r["bio"]
            }

            user!["email"] = "user@rootorboot.com"
            if (r["email"] != nil) {
                user!["email"] = r["email"]
            }

            //                    let locationObj = r.objectForKey("hometown")x
            //                    let location = locationObj!.objectForKey("name") as! String
            //                    print("Location: \(location)")

            //                    let workObj = r.objectForKey("work")
            //                    let workDescription = workObj?.objectForInfoDictionaryKey("description") as! String
            //                    print("Work Description: \(workDescription)")


            var ageDate = NSDate()
            var ageString = NSString()


            var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
            if (r["birthday"] != nil) {
                ageDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(r["birthday"] as! String)!
                print(ageDate)
            }
            else {
                ageDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString("01/01/2003")!
                print(ageDate)
            }
            let ageDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            ageDateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
            print(ageDateFormatter.stringFromDate(ageDate))
            ageString = ageDateFormatter.stringFromDate(ageDate)

            print("AGE STRING: \(ageString)")


            let pictureURL = ((r["picture"] as! NSDictionary)["data"] as! NSDictionary) ["url"] as! String
            let url = NSURL(string: pictureURL)
            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
            NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {
                response, data, error in
                //                        print(ageDate as! String)

                if let ageDateForKey = ageString as? String {

                    let birthday: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(ageDateForKey as String)!
                    var now: NSDate = NSDate()

                    var ageComponents: NSDateComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(.Year, fromDate: birthday, toDate: now, options: [])
                    var age: Int = ageComponents.year
                    user!["age"] = 13

                    if (user!["age"] != nil) {
                        user!["age"] = age
                        print(age)
                    }
                    else if (user!["age"] == nil) {
                        user!["age"] = 13
                        print(age)
                    }

                }
let imageFile = PFFile(name: "avatar.jpg", data: data!)
user!["picture"] = imageFile
user!.saveInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)
```

When I log in (Before SCHEMA fix) - Error Logging In

When I log in (After SCHEMA fix) - User logs in - print(results) runs